# Django Checkbox checked / uncheck with rules

Tags: django, django-forms

Given a Django form with some fields:

```
class FruitsForm(forms.Form):
    fruit_choices = forms.TypedMultipleChoiceField("Fruits I Like", required=True,
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=20)
```

I have a bunch of 3 fruits - Apple, Orange and Pear. When the form is loaded, however, I want only Apple to be pre-selected / pre-checked.

I know that to make a checkbox checked, use the `attrs={'checked' : 'checked'}` dictionary but how do I do it at a more granular level?

In other words, I would like the form to look:

```
 Name: [Text Field]  

 Fruits I Like: Apple  [X]
 Fruits I Like: Orange [ ]
 Fruits I Like: Pear   [ ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this, you want to use [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#initial). Specifying an `initial` value allows you to set a preselected option.

For example, if you're sending your choices as such:`choices = ((1, 'Apple'), (2, 'Orange'), (3, 'Pear'))`, you would do:

`fruit_choices = forms.TypedMultipleChoiceField(label="Fruits I Like", required=True,
 widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices=choices, initial=1)`

If you want this to be rule based, you can also, for example, choose to set `initial = my_initial_fruit` where `my_initial_fruit` is some function defined elsewhere in the project.

Comment: Just one last thing to add: If `initial` has multiple values, then make that a list. For example `initial = [1, 2]`